# Error while choosing a mid pivot element in python quick sort

Tags: python, recursion, quicksort

I have written a quick sort code. It works fine except that one element remains unsorted. I tried debugging but in vain. Could you please help me locate the potential error.

Here is the code.

```
def qsort(l,start,end):

    if start >= end :
       return
    i,j = start, end
    pivot = (start + (end - start)/2)    

    while i<=j:
        while(l[i] < l[pivot]):
            i+=1
        while(l[j] > l[pivot]):
            j-=1
        if(i<=j):
           l[i],l[j] = l[j],l[i]
           i+=1
           j-=1

    qsort(l,start,j)
    qsort(l,i,end)

    return l

    a = [67,89,45,23,15,19,1,14,100]
    print qsort(a,0,len(a)-1)
```

The output of the above code is [1, 14, 15, 23, 19, 45, 67, 89, 100]. For some reason 23 and 19's positions are not interchanged.

However if I select a random pivot with pivot = random.randint(fst,lst) statement I get a completely sorted list.Could someone pls explain the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

You might find these reference implementations helpful while trying to understand your own.

---

**Returning a new list:**

```
def qsort(array):
    if len(array) < 2:
        return array
    head, *tail = array
    less = qsort([i for i in tail if i < head])
    more = qsort([i for i in tail if i >= head])
    return less + [head] + more
```

---

**Sorting a list in place:**

```
def quicksort(array):
    _quicksort(array, 0, len(array) - 1)

def _quicksort(array, start, stop):
    if stop - start > 0:
        pivot, left, right = array[start], start, stop
        while left <= right:
            while array[left] < pivot:
                left += 1
            while array[right] > pivot:
                right -= 1
            if left <= right:
                array[left], array[right] = array[right], array[left]
                left += 1
                right -= 1
        _quicksort(array, start, right)
        _quicksort(array, left, stop)
```

---

**Generating sorted items from an iterable:**

```
def qsort(sequence):
    iterator = iter(sequence)
    head = next(iterator)
    try:
        tail, more = chain(next(iterator), iterator), []
        yield from qsort(split(head, tail, more))
        yield head
        yield from qsort(more)
    except StopIteration:
        yield head

def chain(head, iterator):
    yield head
    yield from iterator

def split(head, tail, more):
    for item in tail:
        if item < head:
            yield item
        else:
            more.append(item)
```

Comment: Thanks. In my code if I assign pivot = start as you did it works perfectly. But I still wanna understand whats possibly wrong in choosing a pivot element in the middle of the list. If you could explain me it would be great.